# Typescript class states

Tags: typescript, type-declaration

Consider `User` class:

```js
class User {
  isAuthenticated: boolean
  friends: User[] | undefined,
}
```

User has friends only if he is authenticated. I want to do this:

```js
declare const user: User

if (user.isAuthenticated) {
  // user.friends is an array of Users
} else {
  // user.friends is undefined
}
```

Splitting the class into two classes `User` and `AnonymousUser` is not a solution.

**UPDATE:** Maybe my question wasn't clear enough. I guarantee that if user `isAuthenticated`, his `friends` field will be an array, otherwise `undefined`. I want to tell typescript about that. Something like this:

```js
class User {
  isAuthenticated: boolean
  // Here I don't know what to do.
  friends: this.isAuthenticated extends true ? User[] : undefined
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *almost* do this using a feature called [**user-defined type guards**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types):

```
class User {
    private isAuthenticated_: boolean;

    public isAuthenticated(): this is User & HasFriends {
        return this.isAuthenticated_;
        // At the call sites, you will need to "guard" some code with a condition
        // involving this function. `this` will get a static type "upgrade" in the
        // `true` branch only.
    }
}

interface HasFriends {
    friends: User[];
}
```

The difference to what you want is that you cannot make the original *property* `User.isAuthenticated` itself serve double duty as a type guard. *Getters* cannot be type guards either, thus the above solution involving a *function*.

Now you can do this:

```
if (someUser.isAuthenticated()) {
    // Here, TypeScript will see `someUser` as being typed `User & HasFriends`
    // and allow you to access its `friends` property (regardless of whether
    // it is actually defined on the object or not).
    celebrateWith(someUser.friends);
}
else {
    // Here, `someUser`'s static type remains unchanged, so friends isn't
    // visible to TypeScript (again, regardless of actual existence at runtime).
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that TypeScript's type checking is *static*. It happens at compile-time. So you can't have TypeScript do type checking that depends on a runtime condition.

You can certainly declare the class the way you have, but it will be entirely possible for an instance to have `isAuthenticated` be `true` while having `friends` be `undefined` (or to have `friends` be an array while `isAuthenticated` is `false`).

For static type-checking of this, you'd need to use the solution you've ruled out in the question: Separate types for anonymous and authenticated users. The action of authenticating an `AnonymousUser` would return an equivalent (but authenticated) `User` object. (The act of revoking authentication would similarly return an equivalent [but unauthenticated] `AnonymousUser` object.)

Given that you don't want to that, I'd say those should be accessor properties so logic within the class can ensure that they're consistent. For instance:

```
class User {
    private _friends: User[] | undefined = undefined;
    get isAuthenticated(): boolean {
        return this.friends !== undefined;
    }
    get friends(): User[] | undefined {
        return this._friends;
    }
}
```

...and then logic within the class makes a user authenticated by setting `this._friends to [];` (or revokes authentication by setting `this._friends = undefined;`). That way, the instance can't be inconsistent, since both properties rely on the same underlying state.

(That example uses TypeScript's version of private, but of course you can use [JavaScript's private fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) instead if you're using those.)

---

If you can guarantee instances will conform to the types, you can use union types for this. Assuming `--strictNullChecks`:

```
declare type UnauthenticatedUser = {
    isAuthenticated: false;
    friends: undefined;
};

declare type AuthenticatedUser = {
    isAuthenticated: true;
    friends: User[];
}

declare type User = UnauthenticatedUser | AuthenticatedUser;

// Works
const u1: User = {
    isAuthenticated: true,
    friends: []
};

// Works
const u2: User = {
    isAuthenticated: false,
    friends: undefined
};

// Errors:
// > Type '{ isAuthenticated: true; friends: undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'User'.
// > Type '{ isAuthenticated: true; friends: undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'AuthenticatedUser'.
// > Types of property 'friends' are incompatible.
// > Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'User[]'."
const u3: User = {
    isAuthenticated: true,
    friends: undefined
};
```

[On the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%2F%2F%20You%20need%20to%20enable%20--strictNullchecks%20(the%20playground%0A%2F%2F%20link%20doesn't%20retain%20it)%0Adeclare%20type%20UnauthenticatedUser%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20isAuthenticated%3A%20false%3B%0A%20%20%20%20friends%3A%20undefined%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Adeclare%20type%20AuthenticatedUser%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20isAuthenticated%3A%20true%3B%0A%20%20%20%20friends%3A%20User%5B%5D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Adeclare%20type%20User%20%3D%20UnauthenticatedUser%20%7C%20AuthenticatedUser%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Works%0Aconst%20u1%3A%20User%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20isAuthenticated%3A%20true%2C%0A%20%20%20%20friends%3A%20%5B%5D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Works%0Aconst%20u2%3A%20User%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20isAuthenticated%3A%20false%2C%0A%20%20%20%20friends%3A%20undefined%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Fails%0Aconst%20u3%3A%20User%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20isAuthenticated%3A%20true%2C%0A%20%20%20%20friends%3A%20undefined%0A%7D%3B%0A)

Then apply the correct type to any given user.

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear enough. I guarantee that if user `isAuthenticated`, his `friends` field will be array, otherwise `undefined`. I want to tell typescript about that. Look at updated question.

Comment: @OlehMisarosh - You can use union types to get there if you *already* know a given user object conforms. (I don't see how you can do that if you're using a `class` with mutable `isAuthenticated` and `friends` properties, though, although perhaps the class above helps.) But if an object ever **changes** from unauthenticated to authenticated, again, that's a runtime thing TypeScript can't check for you. You'd need type assertions around the authentication process.

Comment: "I don't see how you can do that if you're using a class with mutable isAuthenticated and friends properties"
This is a toy example.

What if i want to use that union type, which you provied, with my class? If I copy paste your `User` type declaration to the `User` class, typescript says "Duplicate identifier 'User'".

Comment: In other words, I want `isAuthenticated` to be typeguard